# Dynamic bulk insert silently failing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a job that runs nightly to load a bunch of flat files to a database (around 250 files/tables, runs for around one hour).  It uses a cursor to loop through the tables, and runs the following dynamic query to build and execute a bulk insert of the data.

```
select @sql = 'BULK INSERT tmp.VW_' + @tableName 
        + ' FROM ''' + @filePath + @fileName 
        + '''  WITH(FIELDTERMINATOR = ''' 
        + @fieldTerminator + ''',ROWTERMINATOR = ''' 
        + @rowTerminator + ''', KEEPNULLS,TABLOCK);'                    
exec (@sql)
```

Three times in the past year this statement has silently failed for the entire job.  What I mean by this is the cursor loops through each table, it logs that the data is loaded for all tables, but when I check the data all 250 tables are empty.

When I re-run the job it works fine and all the data is loaded.  When there are issues with the file format, SQL deadlock, TCP connection issues the job stops loading and logs the error.

I have checked the server logs and see nothing, and nothing in my jobs logs either.  I've tried recreating the issue,  but without success.  As I mentioned it has happened 3x in the past year, but 0x in the previous three years this job has run.

Any idea what is happening or how to prevent it?

Comment: does it interfere with your nightly maintenance job?

Comment: There has been no interference from other jobs that we can identify, nothing else at all was running during the last failure.

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap everything in a Try...Catch?

```
BEGIN TRY
  select @sql = 'BULK INSERT tmp.VW_' + @tableName 
        + ' FROM ''' + @filePath + @fileName 
        + '''  WITH(FIELDTERMINATOR = ''' 
        + @fieldTerminator + ''',ROWTERMINATOR = ''' 
        + @rowTerminator + ''', KEEPNULLS,TABLOCK);'                    
  exec (@sql) 
END TRY

GO

-- The previous GO breaks the script into two batches,
-- generating syntax errors. The script runs if this GO
-- is removed.

    BEGIN CATCH
            -- Store exception information casting error message to varchar
            SELECT @IsError = 1, @ErrorMessage = 'Exception message: ' + Cast (Error_Message() as varchar)  + ';'
    END CATCH

    IF @IsError <> 0
    BEGIN
         DECLARE @Subject VARCHAR(250)
         SELECT @Subject = 'Server Name: ' + @@SERVERNAME + '; Database Name: ' +  DB_NAME() + ';' + ' - Email failed'
         EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = 'AlertSupport@abc.com'
                                    , @from_Address = 'sqlemail.abc.com'
                                    , @body = @ErrorMessage
                                    , @subject = @Subject
                                    , @profile_name = 'DBProfileName'

        Raiserror('Error encountered while sending email', 16, 1);

    END
GO
```

I experienced some weirdness a few years back doing something similar.  We never figured out what the issue was, but it seemed like something was taking down SQL my Server overnight.  Eventually I created a VB.NET .exe that fired off every few minutes, using Windows Task Scheduler, and the .exe checked to see if SQL Server was running or not.  If the .exe found SQL Server was not running, it started it up.  We never figured out what was taking it down...

Comment: It actually is wrapped in a try catch, it does not go to the catch, it just keeps running as if all is well.

Comment: Whoa!  Very bizarre.  Well, there has to be a reason for what's happening.  hopefully someone will jump in with a suggestion to help you get it straightened out.